# Use awk on zipped files getting by find commands

Tags: shell, unix

I want to use awk command on the zip files returned by find command, and dump some specific columns from the zip file into the new files having same kind of hierarchy as of zip files.

For example, i have an structure like :

```
/2017/05/25/GAURshvol20170525.txt.zip
/2017/05/26/GAURsh20170526.txt.zip
/2017/05/26/GUPTsh20170526.txt.zip
/2017/05/26/GUPTshvol20170526.txt.zip
/2017/05/26/GAURshvol20170526.txt.zip
/2017/05/30/GAURshvol20170530.txt.zip
/2017/05/30/GAURsh20170530.txt.zip
/2017/05/30/GUPTsh20170530.txt.zip
/2017/05/30/GUPTshvol20170530.txt.zip
/2017/05/31/GAURsh20170531.txt.zip
/2017/05/31/GUPTsh20170531.txt.zip
/2017/05/31/GUPTshvol20170531.txt.zip
```

And in every file inside the zip file i'm having the data as below:

```
20170601|A|69636|122548|Z
20170601|AA|67544|128724|Z
20170601|AAAP|453|1306|Z
20170601|AAC|5840|8962|Z
20170601|AADR|1925|1925|Z
20170601|AAL|289708|344209|Z
20170601|AAMC|10|15|Z
20170601|AAME|100|200|Z
20170601|AAN|44851|72461|Z
20170601|AAOI|42836|82801|Z
20170601|AAON|3417|4127|Z
20170601|AAP|71212|85414|Z
20170601|AAPL|528135|1213451|Z
20170601|AAT|7742|10104|Z
20170601|AAU|2200|2700|Z
20170601|AAV|2746|6797|Z
20170601|AAWW|4662|7298|Z
20170601|AAXJ|54464|57764|Z
20170601|AAXN|45497|48611|Z
```

Now, i want to fetch some specific columns from above and dump these into the new files in a new directory with same kind of hierarchy, like if i have dumped the data in the directory abcd, then hierarchy should be like

```
gaur/2017/05/25/GAURshvol20170525.txt
gaur/2017/05/26/GAURsh20170526.txt
gaur/2017/05/26/GUPTsh20170526.txt
gaur/2017/05/26/GUPTshvol20170526.txt
gaur/2017/05/26/GAURshvol20170526.txt
gaur/2017/05/30/GAURshvol20170530.txt
gaur/2017/05/30/GAURsh20170530.txt
gaur/2017/05/30/GUPTsh20170530.txt
gaur/2017/05/30/GUPTshvol20170530.txt
gaur/2017/05/31/GAURsh20170531.txt
gaur/2017/05/31/GUPTsh20170531.txt
gaur/2017/05/31/GUPTshvol20170531.txt
```

I tried the below commands, (currently my pwd is parent directory of 2017 and gaur):

```
find -name 'GAUR*.zip' -exec awk -F"|" '{print $2,$3 > (FILENAME "-new")}' {} +
```

its leads to infinite wait. i'm more interesting in using regex in find part, if any one could please, for that i used.

```
find . -regex '.^GAUR*\.\(zip\|\)'
```

But failed.

Comment: Check if combination of `find` with `-exec` option calling `zcat |awk` could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all file in current dir recursively start with GAUR and end with .zip, read output by line,create directory, unzip file and redirect the output into awk print 2. and 3. col into a file in the current directory /gaur/original file path (sed cut the .zip extension from the file name) without .zip ending.

```
find -name 'GAUR*.zip' | while read line ; do mkdir -p gaur/$(dirname $line) && unzip -p $line | awk -F"|" '{ print $2","$3 }' > ./gaur/$(echo $line | sed 's/.zip$//g') ; done
```

You have to unzip the file first then you able to run awk on the file. So i made this ugly one liner to do this. But it hard to modify so I would use regular shell script for this.

Comment: Kudos, thanks @Edvin, it worked. hats off boss (Y),
I did it by using shell script.

Comment: could you please let me know, how can i make this failproof?

Comment: The issue could be if you dont have write permission to create folders. If mkdir command failing because of that the unzip will not run. the && not allow the next command to run if first failed. I think the permission issue could be the most common for this one liner.

Comment: If you want to be foolproof command you should write this in shell script, and validate every input, paths, permissions. Before you execute the actual command, and you also able to customize the search pattern, and output file col order if you like.

Comment: Well, there are many pitfalls, for example not quoting variables and the `while read line` pattern has also some bugs. I think my script is free of these problems. No offense Edvin, it's just fast _probably_ working one-liner vs reliable script that is long.

Comment: I had more issue with `for i in "$@"` than `while read line` for this  it would working fine but I like to avoid to use it, since it is not processing the given variables in the given order. I simply don't like this behavior and ti is give me hard time for so many hours. @Mike

Answer (score 1):

This does not have an easy solution because you need both the filename and the content of the file in `awk`. The problem is that you can't use pipelines in `-exec`.

Solution without additional files would be calling `-exec sh -c 'zcat | awk'` but then you would have tons of work with escaping in the awk part.

But the best solution would be to make a script like this:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in "$@" ; do
    mkdir -p gaur/"$(dirname "$i")"
    filename="$(echo gaur/"$i" | sed 's/\.zip$//')"
    zcat "$i" | awk -F'|' -v filename="$filename" '{print $2,$3 > filename}'
done
```

and then simply call:

`find 2017 -regex '.*/GAUR.*\.zip' -exec ./script.sh {} +`